# Can GDAL with "Kml Super Overlay" output a georeferenced geoTiff from a kmz?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I've got a kmz containing an unrefrenced jpg and a boundary box in kml.

ogrinfo is happy to report (filenames redacted):

```
INFO: Open of `Sim[...].kmz'
  using driver `LIBKML' successful.
1: Sim[...]
```

but, gdalinfo reports:

> ERROR 4: `Sim[...].kmz' not recognised as a supported file format.

I've run these info commands with the generic gdal/ogr tools on 14.04 and a specially compiled 1.11.1 using [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120101/building-gdal-with-libkml-support).

Is there a way, using some approximation of these tools (barring manual unzipping and georeferencing of the jpg), to export a geoTiff containing appropriately referenced *raster* data from this data?

Answer (score 2):

In the past, I have used a script to unzip the kmz and extract the bounding box coordinates from the KML and used gdal_translate to georeference the image

The LatLonBox coordinates will map to the following values when using gdal_translate

ulx = west
uly = north
lrx = east
lry = south

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry -a_srs EPSG:4326 input.jpg output.tif
```