# How to install GDAL on CentOS 7.4?

Tags: gdal, centos, compile

I'm trying to install GDAL 2.x on my CentOS 7.4 server.

I looked at what is available, and it is still at v 1.11 of GDAL

Since I need GDAL v 2.x along with libKML support, looks like I'll have to build it from source.

I looked at the documentation for building from source, and I found the details unclear.

- What options to give when configuring the make file?
- How do I specify that I need the libKMl & PostGreSQL Drivers?

Is there a Page/documentation which shows how GDAL 2.x can be compiled from source on a CentOS 7.4 server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found this answer which pointed me in the correct direction: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/120103/442

I just had to update the GDAL version there.

These are the commands that I used to get a successful deployment of GDAL v2.x

```
#Install the tools that we will use
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum install wget

#for Postgresql support
sudo yum install postgresql postgresql-devel

#libkml Support
##---------This part is depending on prebuilt libraries. In the future we may replace this by compiling them from source.
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/etc-data.koordinates.com/gdal-travisci/install-libkml-r864-64bit.tar.gz
tar xzf install-libkml-r864-64bit.tar.gz

#Copy these required files to  /usr/local
sudo cp -r install-libkml/include/* /usr/local/include
sudo cp -r install-libkml/lib/* /usr/local/lib
sudo ldconfig


#download GDAL
wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.2.3/gdal-2.2.3.tar.gz

#Untar
tar xzf gdal-2.2.3.tar.gz
cd gdal-2.2.3

#Compile from source
./configure --with-libkml 
make
make install
```

Comment: Hey can you tell us a way we can do it on heroku.

Comment: @SandeepKumar: I don't know any thing about heroku, but this would be a great question for you to ask here.

Comment: Does this install for all users?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error concerning SFCGAL library and I solve it installing the corresponding devel library

e.g. on Centos 7.4

> sudo yum install SFCGAL-devel

I hope it can be useful also for you

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue and solved it by doing the following:

```
yum -y install epel-release
```

Found this on [AN ALMOST IDIOT'S GUIDE TO INSTALL POSTGRESQL 9.5, POSTGIS 2.2 AND PGROUTING 2.1.0 WITH YUM](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/362-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.5,-PostGIS-2.2-and-pgRouting-2.1.0-with-Yum.html)

Which I got to through https://postgis.net/install/

Section:

Red Hat / Centos / Scientific Linux

3. Refer to [Install PostgreSQL 9.5, PostGIS 2.2, pgRouting 2.1 with Yum](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/362-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.5,-PostGIS-2.2-and-pgRouting-2.1.0-with-Yum.html) for more detailed instructions.